# Azure Cosmos DB (EF/Core) - Camel Case Property Names

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework, azure-cosmosdb

I have a .NET Core 3.1 API Project which has  Cosmos DB storage being handled via Entity Framework (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Cosmos - v3.1.5).

I have a database model:

```
[JsonObject(NamingStrategyType = typeof(CamelCaseNamingStrategy))]
public class BikeRental
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "bikeId")]
    public string BikeId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "shopId")]
    public string ShopId { get; set; }
}
```

Upon saving to the CosmosDB database, the columns are being serialised using the class property names, ignoring the 'PropertyName' attribute. For example, if 'bikeId' is changed to 'testBikeId' it is written as 'BikeId' still.

```
{
    "Id": "192dfdf4-54cb-4290-a478-7035518983ca",
    "BikeId": "eb65b93b-17d3-4829-9729-d48c029211fe2",
    "ShopId": "636c08c4-600d-458a-98b7-8d312b8c18d2",

    "_rid": "2QZIAMVYbVQBAAAAAAAAAA==",
    "_self": "dbs/2QZIAA==/colls/2QZIAMVYbVQ=/docs/2QZIAMVYbVQBAAAAAAAAAA==/",
    "_etag": "\"00000000-0000-0000-4627-f721b0e701d6\"",
    "_attachments": "attachments/",
    "_ts": 1592564051
}
```

Any help or suggestions on how to resolve this would be much appreciated!

Edit:
The saving of the object to Cosmos is performed via:

```
var response = _context.BikeRentals.Add(obj)
_context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: how are you serializing?

Comment: The serialisation is being performed by Entity Framework. So this would happen when adding the object to the relevant context. I have edited the original post to include this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For EF mapping use ColumnAttribute or the fluent configuration in OnModelCreating is used.

In the case of Cosmos you may want the names in the database to be the same as the names when you serialize for sending to the client, but in the general case your entities may map to the database differently than for JSON serialization.

You should use the [Fluent API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/fluent/types-and-properties) and iterate all the entity types, and properties an apply the Pascal-to-Camel-Case transformation.

Comment: Thank you David. Adding a transformation within the OnModelCreating has worked.

Comment: David, sorry to come back on this one. However, although I have now got this working successfully with your recommendation, I am hitting a further problem.

Having the property declared as Id, it's then correctly mapped to 'id'. However, for some reason Cosmos then adds the class type into the ID?  e.g.  "id": "BikeRental|01f7be19-4f0f-44d1-9fa9-721195cf2d45",

Comment: ColumnAttribute does not seem to work in EF Core 6, nor have I seen it in any of the documentation, but using the fluent configuration works great - just a lot more typing. ;)

Comment: I think the reason why ColumnAttributes don't work is because the properties from Dotnet core are mapped to properties in json, not column. But I agree there should have been an alternative attribute for Cosmosdb.

Answer (score 5):

Use Fluent API for model configuration in `OnModelCreating` method:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<BikeRental>().Property(x => x.Id).ToJsonProperty("id");
modelBuilder.Entity<BikeRental>().Property(x => x.BikeId).ToJsonProperty("bikeId");
modelBuilder.Entity<BikeRental>().Property(x => x.ShopId).ToJsonProperty("shopId");
```

Answer (score 1):

I've come up with an extension method to handle this

```
    public static void CamelCasePropertyNames<T>(this EntityTypeBuilder<T> entity)
        where T : class
    {       
        foreach (var property in typeof(T).GetProperties())
        {
            entity.Property(property.Name)
                .ToJsonProperty(char.ToLowerInvariant(property.Name[0]) + property.Name.Substring(1));
        }
    }
```

Edit: Ran into an issue where collection types were failing as this was clashing with OwnsMany, filtering the properties with the below fixes this

```
.Where(p => p.PropertyType.IsGenericType is false)
```

Answer (score 0):

I made my properties with lowercase, property *convention* NOT TODAY !
saved so much **PAIN** with offered solutions such as attributes (Newtonsoft vs System.Text) / API-fluent (if I have many properties will I map every one of them ? even with an extension method it's not so clear, and what about nested classes ?)

Answer (score -2):

The problem with the id is due to not adding

```
  modelBuilder.Entity<BikeRental>().HasNoDiscriminator();
```

If you add this it should just create the id alone